# Tag wiki edit reviews - remove proposal from queue when a new one is created

Tags: discussion, feature-request

From time to time I receive tag wiki edits for approval, and just after approving it I receive its newer version (from the same author)

I suppose that both versions were already in the queue when I've started the review, is it possible to remove old versions from the queue (discard them) when a new version from the same user is proposed?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are **different** reviews.

Take [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discussion) as an example.

One is the main tag wiki (what you see when you click info):

> [image]

The other is the tag wiki **excerpt** - the usage guidance (The bit you see when you hover over the tag):

> [image]

If you edit [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discussion) you can see that there are two **different** edit fields:

> [image]